# no me modifica el style el select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

tengo creado un select con varios valores de colores pero al llamarlos no me hace el cambio en otro componente div donde el background se debería modificar

```
export default class Color extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: '' }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.onColor = this.onColor.bind(this)
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
}

onColor() {
    const cambio = this.state.value
    console.log(cambio)
    return cambio
}

render() {
    return (
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.onColor}>
            <option value='white'>Seleccione un color</option>
            <option value='red'>Rojo</option>
            <option value='green'>Verde</option>
            <option value='blue'>Azul</option>
        </select>
    );
}
```

}

este es el código donde selecciono un color

```
export default class Caja extends Component{    
styles = { backgroundColor: Color.onColor }

render(){
    return(
        <div className='caja' style={this.styles}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

y aquí donde hago "supuestamente" la modificación del style del div
pero no me lo cambia

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header" >
        <Color />
        <Caja />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

y este es el js principal

Comment: ¿Tienes algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: no me sale ningún error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes acceder al estado de un componente asi.

Lo que se aconseja es ["levantar el estado"](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), llevartelo a un ancestro que compartan Color y Caja y pasar como prop lo que necesites.

En este caso tienes 3 componentes:

- App

  - Color (setea el color)
  - Caja (consume el color)

La solucion mas simple es hacer esto:

```javascript
// App component
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onColor = this.onColor.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  onColor() {
    const cambio = this.state.value;
    console.log(cambio);
    return cambio;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Color selectedColor={this.state.value} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleClick={this.onColor} />
          <Caja selectedColor={this.state.value} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```javascript
// Color component
const Color = ({ selectedColor, handleChange, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <select value={selectedColor} onChange={handleChange} onClick={handleClick}>
      <option value="white">Seleccione un color</option>
      <option value="red">Rojo</option>
      <option value="green">Verde</option>
      <option value="blue">Azul</option>
    </select>
  );
};

export default Color;
```

```
// Caja component

const Caja = ({ selectedColor }) => {
  const styles = { backgroundColor: selectedColor };
  return <div className="caja" style={this.styles}></div>;
};


export default Caja;
```

Comment: me salta este error cuando lo ejecuto TypeError: instance.render is not a function

Comment: conviertes los archivos de color y caja a function  o los dejas como class

Comment: vale ya mire mejor y es que no haces ninguna function en color y caja únicamente creas los valores y los envías. Gracias

Comment: Claro, los dejo como functional components, me alegro que te haya funcionado

Answer (score 1):

veo que en la linea donde añadís el style de los colores dice "backgroundColor" no existe dicho atributo, el que podes usar son dos: "background-color" o bien solo "background"

entonces quedaría así:

```
export default class Caja extends Component{    
 styles = { background-color: Color.onColor }

 render(){
 return(
    <div className='caja' style={this.styles}>
    </div>
 )
 }
}
```

cualquier cosa me avisas, saludos!

Comment: le he probado pero sigue sin cambiarme el color del div voy a añadir donde tengo el principal por si es algo de las etiquetas

Comment: Puede ser que se trate por el `class` también, en el código pusiste `className` prueba solo con `class`

Comment: si lo cambio a class me salta un error de nombre y el className es para que me detecte el css del borde y tamaño

Comment: Hola @Daniel, favor edita tu respuesta y agrega el codigo en formato de codigo para que tu respuesta sea mas clara a la comunidad.

Comment: te entiendo lo del `className`, por otro lado veo que el atributo style en tu div no esta contenido por ninguna comilla, prueba agregándole unas comilla quedaría así `style="{this.styles}"`